# Excel Custom Functions using Add-Ins: "This add-in is no longer available" error

Tags: excel, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I followed all of the steps [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-custom-functions-quickstart?tabs=excel-windows) to try and load in a basic excel custom function add in. Everything in the setup stages seems to work, however, when I run 'npm run start:desktop' and Excel opens, there is an error on the side that says:

> ADD-IN ERROR This add-in is no longer available: add-ins inserted during development are only available during debugging from Visual Studio. Please open your project in Visual Studio and re-run your application, or deploy your application into a valid catalog and re-insert

I get this error whether I run the project from the command line, VS Code, or Visual Studio. I am on Windows 10 using Excel 2016.

Here is a photo of the Excel page with the error: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Even though question is old one and I think OP must have resolved this problem. However I am currently facing the exact same problem so often. Below are my work arounds which are working for me, it might help others.

1. Clear Excel Cache in Trust center settings and run application again.
2. Many times options 1 does not work, then I make change in Add-in menifest to make it invalid and then undo these changes and run application.
3. If both options fails, then restart Visual Studio.
4. If all other options fails, restart my system, and then this issue is resolved.
5. If still problem persists, Uninstall Office workload from Visual studio, install it again and check. If problem persists then repair office.

These 5 workarounds have so far worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Clearing the Office cache sometimes fixes this: [Clear the cache](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/testing/clear-cache?view=common-js)

**UPDATE 1/23/2021:**

There is now a troubleshooting section for this error: [Getting error "This add-in is no longer available"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/troubleshoot-development-errors#getting-error-this-add-in-is-no-longer-available).

Comment: I did this but unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: You may can check [runtime log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/runtime-logging) to see if there is anything unexpected.

Comment: Or you you may have a try on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins#:~:text=In%20Excel%2C%20Word%2C%20or%20PowerPoint,to%20insert%20the%20add-in.) to see if it could help at least load the add-in successfully.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I compared the manifest with a boilerplate manifest and I could not find any notable differences. If I go to https://localhost:3000/taskpane.html in the browser, it is shown correctly. I have used it on 3 different machines and everywhere the ame error. I deploy it to azure as well but I want to use the development environment for testing. I have no idea where to look anymore? What else could I try?